# Dynamically change visibility of fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, visibility

I want to dynamically change the visibility of `fragment1` when the User clicks `button` on the `Main Activity`. `fragment1` is initialised as visible but when the button is pressed, `fragment1` changes to hidden.

I've read that it's dangerous to change the visibility of fragments within an activity and subsequently should be either handled with `Fragment Manager` eg.

```
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    final fragment_one fragment1 = new fragment_one();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1);
    fragmentTransaction.show(fragment1);    //or .hide(fragment1);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

However, my understanding is that once the fragment is committed it has been effectively initialised and so to change its state requires it to be replaced and therefore go through the aforementioned process? This seems incredibly cumbersome to change something some preliminary.

Obviously the button needs to be in the `Main Activity` otherwise, if it was possible to toggle visibility states it'll be impossible to revert from a invisible state to a visible one.

With that in mind, I implemented the following but it has no effect on the fragment - which is what I suspected as I had already committed the fragment. NB: The following is in the onCreate method in `Main Activity` after committing the fragment which was detailed above.

Any advice would be great thanks.

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fragmentTransaction.hide(fragment1);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was one issue of a much larger problem I was facing with animating a nested fragment with `ObjectAnimator` and then toggling its visibility.

To anyone trying to toggle the visibility of the fragment, it seems you can only change the affect change on the `ViewGroup` included in the arguments for `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1);`. In this case it would've been `fragment_container`. As this is the rootView, changing this was sufficient as I wanted the entire card to disappear.

Also worth noting this was supposed to be a child fragment. Consequently, using `getFragmentManager` was incorrect. I avoided `getChildFragmentManager` because I was receiving a series of errors that were becoming increasingly complex. After changing the `ViewGroup` that I was adding my child fragment (changed it to a `FrameLayout` within the parent `Fragment`), this was quickly resolved.